# How to troubleshoot Android push notification using notification hub azure error "Manifest merger failed with multiple errors"?

Tags: android, azure, notifications, push, azure-notificationhub

Trying to implement push notification for my android app with the help of Notification Hubs service.
I have followed all the steps given in [Push notification in Android using Notification hub](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-gcm-get-started/)

But I am getting following  error : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Following is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.microsoft.aad.taskapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
   release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```